# Firebase user authentication multiple users on different instances

Tags: firebase, express, firebase-authentication, react-router

I'm creating a firebase application that uses user authentication, in addition to an express server for video calling with Twilio. Right now, I'm not quite sure how to test signing in multiple users to my application, as when I open different tabs to localhost:3000 both windows redirect to the same location whenever I change the route (using react-router-dom). Therefore, when I try to sign in on a different tab, all other tabs will redirect to the sign in page instead of remaining on the home dashboard.

Could this be a problem with how I'm handling users in Firebase, or how I'm testing with express?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Authentication doesn't really support signing in multiple users into a single app instance.  That sign-in is shared globally among all tabs loaded with the same site.  If you try to sign in a new user, the old one will be immediately and forcefully signed out.  This is true on all client app platforms, including iOS and Android.

If you want to test two users signed into your site at the same time, try two different browsers, or use two different Chrome profiles, so that the per-user storage is different for each browser window.